# Optimized way to compare two lists

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, unity-game-engine, compare

I need to compare two lists with values for graph print. If the values are the same I do nothing, when something is changed then graph is being reprinted. It works but in Unity it lag for a little moment, but enough to notice stutter. I guess the fact that I'm downloading values from web every second is not helping either. I posted my code below, is there any way to make it quicker?

```
void MinMaxPosition(UILineRenderer graph)
{
    bool equals = true;
    MaxPosition = this.GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.Max() + this.GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.Max() * 0.0003f;
    MinPosition = this.GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.Min() - this.GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.Min() * 0.0003f;
    print(MaxPosition);
    print(MinPosition);
    for(int i = 0;i<graph.Points.Count();i++)
    {
        if (((graph.Points[i].y / 0.8) * MaxPosition - MinPosition) + MinPosition != this.GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.ElementAt(i))
        {
            equals = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.Count != lastSize || equals == false)
    {
        ReprintGraph(graph);
    }
    lastSize = GetComponent<TextReader>().prices.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd recommend is to cache the result from GetComponent() -- that's usually a pretty expensive operation, and you're calling it in a tight loop. I'd also be really careful about trying to do comparisons with floating-point numbers; that's liable to be off by very small amounts due to floating-point precision issues and resulting in calling ReprintGraph(graph) more often than you expect; it's probably better to use Mathf.Approximately(). So I'd rewrite that code block more like this.

```
TextReader _textReader = null;
void MinMaxPosition(UILineRenderer graph)
{
    bool equals = true;
    if (_textReader == null)
    {
        _textReader = this.GetComponent<TextReader>();
    }

    MaxPosition = _textReader.prices.Max() + _textReader.prices.Max() * 0.0003f;
    MinPosition = _textReader.prices.Min() - _textReader.prices.Min() * 0.0003f;
    print(MaxPosition);
    print(MinPosition);
    for(int i = 0;i<graph.Points.Count();i++)
    {
        if (!Mathf.Approximately( ((graph.Points[i].y / 0.8) * MaxPosition - MinPosition) + MinPosition , _textReader.prices.ElementAt(i)) )
        {
            equals = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (_textReader.prices.Count != lastSize || equals == false)
    {
        ReprintGraph(graph);
    }
    lastSize = _textReader.prices.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) What's GetComponent()? Some DI engine? Which one? If you're using Ninject, that's the slowest one out there and you should switch to a faster one.

2) Whatever GetComponent() is, why are you calling it 50 times in that method? Just call it once at the top and save TextReader instance. If you're using a slow DI engine, that'll get expensive.

3) How many points are in the list?

4) Check if there are lighter methods then the ones you are using. I.e. Count() vs. Length, ElementAt vs. [], etc.

5) This one will require more work, but do the values REALLY change every second? If not, you are wasting a lot of time grabbing & comparing every second. Figure out how often they'll REALLY change and figure out how much delay is acceptable. One solution is to push them when they change rather then poll in a loop.

If it was me, first optimization I would make was getting rid of the 50 GetComponent() calls and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE .GetComponent() or GameObject.Find() in the runtime.** It's takes too much of resources. **If you need to do this -- you need to do this in start or awake.**

If possible, you need to use transform.Find() (or transform.FindChild -- the same as transform.Find -- so no matter). This is more light-weight func than GameObject.Find()

Possibly this is reason why you have lags. Try to fix this firstly and write me results and newer code if lags will be not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One other suggestion... I'm assuming you will have multiple clients, correct? So what I would suggest doing is doing something light weight like a int/long "version" that you get when you pull the list. So on the server, whenever the list changes, you bump up the version and the client keeps track of what version it has, now diffing the lists is nothing more then comparing what version the client has vs what the server has.